# Pandas: use groupby to sum while aggregating certain values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```py
      Pasture  Surface
Farm                  
01     Sown 1        2
01     Sown 2        3
01    Natural        3
01        Hay        5
02       Sown        7
```

I'd like to group over the farm, in a way that for each farm there will be only 2 pasture values, `sown` and `not sown`, with the first having the sum of the surfaces that have "Sown" in the relative `Pasture` value and the second the sum of all the others. Basically what I want to obtain is:

```
      Pasture  Surface
Farm                  
01       Sown        5
     Not sown        8
02       Sown        7
```

I managed to do it by replacing the names before with the relative one and then using .groupby(), but I was wondering if there was a way to it all in a .groupby() call, or in any case which would be the best way. Thanks!

(P.S.: this is my first question on Stack Overflow, please let me know if I could have done something better!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
sown_or_not = np.where(df.Pasture.str.contains('Sown'), 'Sown', 'Not Sown')

df.groupby(['Farm', sown_or_not]).Surface.sum()
```

Output:

```
Farm          
1     Not Sown    8
      Sown        5
2     Sown        7
Name: Surface, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really nice solution